# How to use afl-fuzz (American Fuzzy Lop) with openssl

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, gcc, openssl, testing

I am trying to use afl-fuzz with openssl in Ubuntu. A normal usage of afl-fuzz would be:

```
afl-gcc test.c //-- this will produce a.out

mkdir testcases
echo "Test case here." > testcases/case1

afl-fuzz -i testcases -o findings ./a.out
```

Now for openssl it would be something like:

```
afl-gcc ./config
make //-- not sure of this :)
afl-fuzz -i test -o findings <exe_name>
```

where "test" is the folder with testcases for openssl

My question is what is the parameter for "exe_name" for openssl? And please correct me if i'm wrong with the rest of the code. Thank you

Comment: Do you remember doing it? I am also compiling openssl with afl-gcc but it is causing issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm exactly sure what you mean by "parameter for "exe_name" for openssl", but:

```
afl-fuzz -i test -o findings ~/path/to/binary/to/fuzz @@
```

will fuzz the binary at `~/path/to/binary/to/fuzz`, substituting `@@` with the path the mutated test case generated from the seed files in `test`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use openssl binary just as it is. You need to write a separete program that will use openssl libraries and then fuzz its exe with afl-fuzz.

Whole process will go like that

Download openssl

```
1. ./config // If you disable something here like no-comp then you have to run`make depend`.
2. Replace gcc with afl-gcc in Makefile 
3. make && make install
```

This process will compile openssl with afl-gcc and you can look how instrumention will be added to object files. In end you will get `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` files in openssl directory.

After successful compilation of openssl, use it in a sample application say sample.c and then compile this file

```
4. afl-gcc sample.c -o sample libssl.a libcrypto.a -ldl
```

and then finally perform fuzzing
    5. afl-fuzz -i testcases -o findings -m none -- ./sample

You can look at [this](https://blog.hboeck.de/archives/868-How-Heartbleed-couldve-been-found.html) and [this](https://github.com/ThalesIgnite/afl-training/issues/1) to get some idea and even find sample files.